# I want to resize frame horizontal as well as vertical

Tags: javascript, html

I want to resize code horizontally as well as vertically. When one frame goes to near other frame also pushing with first frame and move both frames.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
function getFrameSize(frameID) {
    var result = {height:0, width:0};
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var frame = parent.document.getElementById(frameID);
        if (frame.scrollWidth) {
            result.height = frame.scrollHeight;
            result.width = frame.scrollWidth;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
</script>
</head>
    <frameset rows="42,*" cols="*">
        <frame src="menu_bar.html" name="topmenu" noresize="noresize" marginwidth="20">
            <frameset rows="*" cols="33%,33%,33%" border="20" bordercolor="silver">
                <frameset rows="25%,25%,25%" framespacing="2" border="2" bordercolor="2">
                    <frame Id="frameID" name="google" src="frame_a.html" marginwidth="20">
                    <frame src="frame_b.html" marginwidth="20">             
                    <frame src="frame_c.html" marginwidth="20">
                </frameset>
                <frameset rows="25%,25%,25%" framespacing="2" border="2" bordercolor="2">
                    <frame src="frame_d.html" marginwidth="20">
                    <frame src="frame_e.html" marginwidth="20">
                    <frame src="frame_f.html" marginwidth="20">
                </frameset>
                <frameset rows="25%,25%,25%" framespacing="2" border="2" bordercolor="2" id="foo">
                    <frame src="frame_g.html"  marginwidth="20">
                    <frame src="frame_h.html" Id="idFrame"  marginwidth="20">
                    <frame src="frame_i.html"  marginwidth="20">
                </frameset>
      </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to explain your question a little more. What are you trying to do, what is working and what isn't? Also note, framesets are [no longer part of the HTML standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/frameset)

Comment: if you say i send you video...... but how can i send you video???? i don't know .......

Comment: I never talked about videos. Are you using a translation site? I'm sorry, but we can't help you if you don't speak English more than that.

Comment: when one frame goes towards other frame then other frame also goes with first frame towards third frame.